# How to add Oauth Bearer token in QTP

Tags: rest, automation, hp-uft

I'm working on HP UFT Rest API Testing where i need to Pass "Authorization : Bearer " to perform or execute the Rest Service request then only my service will execute and displays the response.

Can any one give me the solutions,How to add Oauth Bearer token in QTP for Rest API Testing.

Answer (score 0):

Please refere below link :

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/task_API_coding_manipulate_WSC_properties.htm

There will be methods associated with the every block/methods , you can write C# code to append the string to the output of authorization operation and store in a global variable- that can be passed as a input to subsequent operation.

BeforeMethod , aftermethods are some of  Event Handlers that are assosicated with each operation.